# Dynamique Select box Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

the data displayed and removed instantly

im trying to create a dynamique select box with laravel , get the data from database and then select one to get the data related to it by id .
i made those methode :

**Jquery**

```
@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('change','.state_id',function(){
            var state_id=$(this).val();
            var div=$(this).parent();
            var op="";
            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('finddelegName')!!}',
                data:{'id':state_id},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.length);
                    op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>chose delegation</option>';
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        op+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name_ar+'</option>';
                    }
                    div.find('.name_fr').html("delegation_id");
                    div.find('.name_fr').append(op);
                },
                error:function(){
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
    public function finddelegName(Request $request){
        $data=Delegation::where('state_id',$request->id)->take(100)->get();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

when i select one from the box ( like the photo ) it console to me the data and then removed
[image: select data from Select box]
[image: consol my data]
how can i fix it ?
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your delegation field should be dropdown. So, you suppose to have this as the field:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="delegation_id" ></select>
```

Then, you will able to inject your ajax response into it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('change','.state_id',function(){
            var state_id=$(this).val();
            var div=$(this).parent();
            var op="";
            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('finddelegName')!!}',
                data:{'id':state_id},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#delegation_id").append("<option value=''> Select Delegation</option>");
                    $.each(data, function(i, item){
                       $("#delegation_id").append("<option value='" + 
                       data[i].delegation_id + "'>" + data[i].delegation_value + " 
                       </option>");
                    });                   
                },
                error:function(){
                }
            })
            $("#delegation_id").empty();

;
        });
});
```

Comment: when i select other value from first box , it get the data and add it to the second box  last data not replace it

Comment: I've added `$('#delegation_id').empty()`. This will clear the data and replace the information in it if it get you correctly.